# Find last inserted record in YiiMongoDbSuite of Yii

Tags: mongodb, yii-extensions, yii

How can I find the last inserted record in YiiMongoDbSuite
I have tried the following

```
$criteria =  array('condition'=>array('userid'=>array('==' => $user_id)),
                    'sort'=>array('lastUpdateDate'=>-1), 
                    'limit'=>1,
                    'skip'=>0 
                );
            $select = array('url','title','userid');
            $arr = $this->find($criteria,$select);
```

But it shows the first record only

Comment: `EMongoCriteria::SORT_DESC` in place of the `-1` at: `array('lastUpdateDate'=>-1),` should do it

Comment: @Sammaye tried that, but no change

Comment: Maybe there is only one entry with the `$user_id`.

Comment: @user714965 no, there are many , but this returns the first one only

Comment: I think your condition is wrong, try: `$d=new EMongoCriteria(); $d->userid('==',$user_id); $d->sort(array('lastUpdateDate'=>EMongoCriteria::SORT_DESC)); $d->limit(1); $d->skip(0);` and then sue the criteria object

Comment: @Sammaye when using that I am getting an error Missing argument 2 for EMongoCriteria::sort(),

Comment: Hmm well that bad, the document says that should work, hmm

Comment: @Sammaye I think there is a bug , see http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimongodbsuite/#c13036 and using that method solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method in http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiimongodbsuite/#c13036 solved the issue .
Replaced the `find()` method by the method mentioned in it.
Based on the above url's suggestion I created a function

```
function MongoFind($criteria,$model){
        $cursor = $model::model()->getCollection()->find($criteria->getConditions());
        if($criteria->getSort() !== null)
            $cursor->sort($criteria->getSort());
        if($criteria->getOffset() !== null)
            $cursor->skip($criteria->getOffset());
        if($criteria->getSelect())
            $cursor->fields($criteria->getSelect(true));
        $cursor->limit(1);

        return $model::model()->populateRecord($cursor->getNext());
    }
```

and used

```
 `$arr= Utils::MongoFind($criteria,$this);`
```

instead of

```
`$arr = $this->find($criteria,$select);`
```